# bitbake-layers add-layer meta-python meta-raspberrypi failed

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto

I have a Raspberry 4 model B and was trying to build Yocoto linux from Ubuntu for installation. I was following https://medium.com/@shantanoodesai/run-docker-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-yocto-project-551d6b615c0b instructions. At step

```
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-raspberrypi
```

I encountered the following errors

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Yocto/RaspberryPi/build $ bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake-layers", line 93, in <module>
    ret = main()
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake-layers", line 61, in main
    tinfoil.prepare(True)
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/tinfoil.py", line 408, in prepare
    self.run_command('parseConfiguration')
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/tinfoil.py", line 466, in run_command
    raise TinfoilCommandFailed(result[1])
bb.tinfoil.TinfoilCommandFailed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 74, in runCommand
    result = command_method(self, commandline)
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 275, in parseConfiguration
    command.cooker.parseConfiguration()
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 427, in parseConfiguration
    self.handleCollections(self.data.getVar("BBFILE_COLLECTIONS"))
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 1225, in handleCollections
    raise CollectionError("Errors during parsing layer configuration")
bb.cooker.CollectionError: Errors during parsing layer configuration

pi@raspberrypi:~/Yocto/RaspberryPi/build $ bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-raspberrypi
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake-layers", line 93, in <module>
    ret = main()
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake-layers", line 61, in main
    tinfoil.prepare(True)
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/tinfoil.py", line 408, in prepare
    self.run_command('parseConfiguration')
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/tinfoil.py", line 466, in run_command
    raise TinfoilCommandFailed(result[1])
bb.tinfoil.TinfoilCommandFailed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 74, in runCommand
    result = command_method(self, commandline)
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 275, in parseConfiguration
    command.cooker.parseConfiguration()
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 427, in parseConfiguration
    self.handleCollections(self.data.getVar("BBFILE_COLLECTIONS"))
  File "/home/pi/Yocto/RaspberryPi/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 1225, in handleCollections
    raise CollectionError("Errors during parsing layer configuration")
bb.cooker.CollectionError: Errors during parsing layer configuration
```

Can anyone advise what should be fixed?

my gcc-multilib  install also failed

```
sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath socat libsdl1.2-dev xterm python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'git' instead of 'git-core'
Package gcc-multilib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-multilib' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: did you follow order of adding layers bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/poky/meta
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/poky/meta-poky
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/poky/meta-yocto-bsp
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-raspberrypi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue with `bitbake-layers` tool in warrior release here, so an alternative is to try to open `conf/bblayers.conf` file in an editor and delete the last entry/line ( probably one containing meta-networking ) in `BBLAYERS` variable and save the file. Now continue with the `bitbake-layers add-layer`

```
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python
bitbake-layers add-layer ../layers/meta-raspberrypi
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems this exists in Zeus too. Is this a known issue?

Comment: perhaps yes, I would suggest to file a bug with bugzilla.yoctoproject.org

Answer (score 1):

i got same error and solved with below methods

1. all layers should be on same branch. like meta-raspberripi , meta-openembedded , meta-poky should be on same zeus branch.
   we can check we are on which branch by git branch.
   we can mover to branch by git checkout zeus.
2. if you already got error their then open bblayers.conf and delete last added layers before adding new layers again (as suggested above).